# Can't connect to mssql server on ubuntu because script is in upgrade mode

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, upgrade, mode

When I want to login as 'sa' user in my mssql server by this command:

```
   sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa
```

I got this error:

```
  'Reason: Server is in script upgrade mode. Only administrator can connect at this time..'
```

I read about -T902 parameter, who is connected to this problem, but don't know how to start mssql server with that paramater in Ubuntu, if it's needed. I also ran mssql-conf script and choose 2) Developer option and setup a password for 'sa' user. I also use DBeaver tool. What shall I do? Thx in an advance.

System:

Ubuntu 17.10

SQL Server (latest version) - 14.0.3022.28-2

Dbeaver - 4.3.5

Comment: Find a solution to connect on. After I ran this command in console

'sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf traceflag 902  on'

I could connect to mssql server through DBeaver as well through ubuntu terminal.

I think I have to upgrade master database. Now I will try to figure it out how.

Comment: Any final Solution to this?

Comment: @MarkoGavranovic thank you, you just saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Got the same error, I waited a few minutes, tried again and it function normally